# Finding the flux of the surface $z=a-x^2-y^2$ lying above $z=b<a$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am stuck on the following question about finding the flux:

> Find the flux of $\vec F= (x,y,z)$ upward through the part of the surface $z=a-x^2-y^2$ lying above the plane $z=b<a$

My attempt:

*Assumptions*

- $z=a-x^2-y^2$ is an infinite paraboloid?
- $z = b < a$ is a plane less than $a$? does this make sense?

Since it is difficult to visualize this problem, I tried to go the "hard way", i.e. by computing the surface element without any consideration of the geometrical properties. i.e.:

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = r\cos \theta  \hfill \\
  y = r\sin \theta  \hfill \\
  z = a - r^2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
Thus,

$$d\vec S = \widehat NdS =  \pm \frac{{\partial (x,y,z)}}{{\partial (r,\theta )}} = (0,0,r)$$
Now, by taking the field $\vec F$ times the surface element, we get:
$$(x,y,z)*(0,0,r) = z*r = (a - 1)r$$
Thus,
$$\iint\limits_D {(ar - r)drd\theta }$$

The difficulty I am having is in my assumption list. I am unable to find the boundaries. I think we should look at the intersection between the surfaace and the plane, although I am not sure.

**Edit:**
The answer is $\pi(3a^2-4ab+b^2)/2$ (according to the key).

Comment: The third coordinate should be $z=a-x^2-y^2 = a-r^2$ instead of $z=a-1$.

Comment: @user197427, thank you for noticing this error!

Comment: As for the boundaries, you can visualize this surface as a paraboloid that opens downward.  Then you slice this horizontally and take the top portion.  The widest part of this piece will be where the plane $z=b$ intersects the $z=a-r^2$, as you mentioned.  This gives you a circle given by $b=a-r^2$, giving the upper bound for the $r$.

Comment: I think I get it! Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use spherical coordinates to evaluate the surface integral.  Note that $\vec F=\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz=\hat  rr$ in spherical coordinates and that the outer unit normal of the sphere is $\hat n = \hat r$.  Thus, the flux is

$$\text{flux}=\int_S \vec F \cdot \hat n dS=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\theta_0}(\hat  ra)\cdot \hat r a^2\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$$

where $\theta_0 = \arccos (b/a)$.  Thus,

$$\text{flux}=2\pi a^3(1-b/a)$$

Comment: I think I partly follow the argument. But, is the surface $2\pi a^3(1-b/a)$ different from $\pi(3a^2-4ab+b^2)/2?$ It seems like the key had a different answer. In your answer, how is the fact used that $z=b<a$?

Comment: I guess maybe it is obvious when converting it into spherical coordinates, although I unfortunately, I don't think I follow that.